# Does anyone know an optimization problem this problem could be adapted to?

Tags: graph-theory, optimization

Imagine I have given a $n \times n$ matrix $A:=[a_{i,j}]_{i,j \in \{1,...,n\}}$ of values and I want to have the sum as shown here:

$$\sum_{i\leq j}a_{ij}$$

which just corresponds to the sum of the upper triagle, so e.g. if $A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & 9
\end{pmatrix}$
it corresponds to the sum $1+2+3+5+6+9=26$

Now I want to change the order of the elements in order to maximize the score, i.e. if I change element 2 with element 1 it corresponds to changing the column 2 with column 1 and the row 2 with row 1 which would be equal to:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & 9
\end{pmatrix}\to \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & 3 \\
5 & 4 & 6 \\
8 & 7 & 9
\end{pmatrix} \to \begin{pmatrix}
5 & 4 & 6 \\
2 & 1 & 3 \\
8 & 7 & 9
\end{pmatrix}=:\tilde{A}$$

and the resulting sum would be $5+4+6+1+3+9=28$

Now I want to maximize the sum, so I want to flip rows and columns in order to find the maximum sum of the elements but I can't find a connection to a problem where there is already a solution;

I can display the problem as a graph: Then $a_{ij}$ can correspond to the weight of the edge from $i$ to $j$ and $a_{ii}$ is the weight of an edge from vertex $i$ to itself. Since the diagonal entries always stay on the diagonal and hence do not influence the maximality of the sum we can also set them all equal to zero so we do not have edges from a vertex to itself.

I then look for the permutation $\pi$ where the sum of the edge weights is maximized, only considering the edge weights $a_{ij}$ where $i<j$

Now I am particularly interested in the following:

1. Is this problem NP-complete? I thought of adapting this problem to the Traveling Salesmen Problem because I think the problem is similar and should be NP-complete but I cant transform it yet
2. What would be a smart solution to solve the problem without checking all $n!$ permutations?

Update: I tried a branch-and-bound algorithm as it was suggested:

I calculated an example; Imagine we have 4 vertices; Then our tree is given by:
[image: Step 0]

Now assume our matrix is very simple; We have only 2 values: $0<a<b$ and the matrix is given by $a_{31}=b$, $a_{13}=a$ and for all other entries $a_{ij}=b$ if $i<j$ and $a_{ij}=a$ if $i>j$.

Now I start with k=2 meaning I check the first edges; If $a_{ij}<a_{ji}$ I can cancel the braches where the first and second vertices are $i$ and $j$; This means that the first vertex can't be $4$ because no matter what the second vertex is, we always get a higher score when flipping them; Also these combinations are not possible: $(1,3)$, $(2,1)$ and $(3,2)$; This leads to the reduced tree:

[image: Step 1]

Now I go on to the next step and looking at edges one level lower: The permutation: 1->4->2 is not possible because 1->2->4 is still in the tree; For example, however, 1->4->3 is not possible to cut because we do not have 1->3->4 in the tree anymore (in this case it would be of course possible but I cant generally assume that)
Also I can cut off 2 ->4 ->3 because we still have 2 ->3 ->4 in the tree and 3->4->1 because we have 3->1->4
So the reduced tree will be:

[image: Step 2]

Now finally we will look at the lowest layer. 1->2->4->3 is not possible because we have: 1->2->3->4; Also not possible: 2->3->4->1 and 3->1->4->2;

So the final tree is:
[image: Step 3]

So I was able to reduce the set of 4!=24 permutations to 6 permutations;

Is this how you meant it? Was it correct when I said "For example, however, 1->4->3 is not possible to cut because we do not have 1->3->4 in the tree anymore (in this case it would be of course possible but I cant generally assume that)"?

Comment: We can neglect the diagonal entries whether they're zero or not - they will always stay on the diagonal when you swap two indices, so they'll always be part of the sum.

Comment: You are right... I corrected it; But do you have an idea for a deterministic algorithm? Would it help if the matrix has only zeros and ones?

Comment: [Knuth, Stanford GraphBase](https://books.google.com/books?isbn=0321606329) has a "cautious descent" heuristic and c code for this problem: Econ_order, pages 100-105.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is NP-hard.

Suppose that the input matrix is the adjacency matrix of a directed graph, with $a_{ij} = 1$ whenever there is an edge from $i$ to $j$ and $a_{ij} = 0$ otherwise. In this case, we want to order the vertices such that as many of the $1$'s of the matrix end up in the upper triangle.

This is equivalent to finding a minimum [feedback arc set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback_arc_set) of the graph: the minimum set of edges to delete so that the graph becomes acyclic. For the adjacency matrix of an acyclic graph, we can find a topological sort of the vertices that puts *all* the $1$'s in the upper triangle; so the minimum feedback arc set tells us the fewest number of $1$'s we're forced to leave in the lower triangle.

Unfortunately, the feedback arc set problem is NP-complete.

We can think of the general problem as being a similar problem, but about weighted complete directed graphs; equivalently, weighted tournaments. In this case, the optimal ordering of the indices is called a *median order* of the tournament. The problem obviously gets no harder when we allow arbitrary weights, but here are some papers: [1](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0377221789904426),  [2](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X96001665). If you have access to them, they basically tell you that there's no good methods, but here are some that are least bad.

Basically, the strategy they employ is a branch-and-bound algorithm. All $n!$ orderings of the indices of your matrix can be thought of as leaves of a tree where you fix the positions of the indices one at a time. So at the top node, no positions are fixed. It has $n$ children based on which row/column we make the first one; then each of those has $n-1$ children based on the second row/column, and so on.

With branch-and-bound, we explore the most promising branches of the tree first, and use those to eliminate other branches without looking at them. If you have a particular ordering of the matrix, with a given upper triangle sum, and you're looking at a partial solution with the first $k$ rows fixed, if those $k$ rows have already made the triangle sum guaranteed to be smaller than your particular solution, no matter how the rest is filled, we can discard that partial solution.

Another paper [3](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1568494615007978) gives a randomized algorithm for the zero-one case (the feedback arc set problem) in particular.

Comment: Thank you so much for your idea - but please allow me some time to properly understand it - I'll further comment it in a bit

Comment: I understand why the problem is NP-hard (I unfortunately did not know this NP-complete problem)... But unfortunately I have omitted one fact that I also know about the matrix $A$; For every entry $a_{i,j}$ of $A$ we have: $a_{i,j} \geq a_{i,k}a_{k,j}$.  It would be now interesting to prove that it is still NP-hard (if it is actually  true). In case it is true I thought taking the reachability matrix of a graph, so $a_{ij}=1$ if there is a path from $i$ to $j$ and $0$ otherwise. Then we have $a_{i,j} \geq a_{i,k}a_{k,j}$. But now I am stuck with finding a connection to an NP-complete problem

Comment: In the $\{0,1\}$ case (the case of a reachability matrix) this restriction seems to make the problem much easier: the strongly-connected components contribute the same to the sum no matter how they're internally ordered, so we just want a topological sort of the strongly connected components. I don't have much intuition for what the condition $a_{ij} \ge a_{ik} a_{kj}$ does for arbitrary matrices.

Comment: Oh that's right, you are really smart... And if I consider all strongly-connected components as vertices, then the resulting graph is a DAG because if there is a cycle between the vertices, it means that there is a cycle between two strongly-connected components which is obviously not possible; Therefore I can easily find the right topological sort (which might be not unique) of the strongly-connected components right? And since finding the strongly-connected components can also be done very efficiently, finding the right permutation is also very easy, right?

Comment: Yep; in that case, it should be an $O(n \log n)$-ish algorithm.

Comment: Okay that is already a good step forward - but the very interesting part would be about the general case; But maybe I have an idea about it later; May I ask about the branch-and-bound algorithm? I understood how you construct the tree, but I do not understand how you'd continue then

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the full idea myself. But the basic is that depending on the reordering of the matrix $A$ that we choose, either $a_{ij}$ or $a_{ji}$ is in the upper triangle, but not both. If we fix a partial ordering of $1,2,\dots,n$, which is an ordering of $1,2,\dots,k$ for some $k<n$, then we know which of $a_{ij}$ or $a_{ji}$ is in the upper triangle for $i,j \le k$.

Comment: This gives us a lower bound and an upper bound on the overall sum based on if we choose the better or worse of $a_{ij}$ or $a_{ji}$ for all other pairs. So we explore promising branches of the tree, and prune a branch for which the lower bound is worse than another branch's upper bound.

Comment: I can follow you when you say either $a_{ij}$ or $a_{ji}$ is in the upper triangle but never both; But then I do not entirely understand your idea; Are you looking on random $i$, $j$ or just neighboring ones(i=j+1 or i=j-1)? Maybe an example would be helpful: You say I start with a particular ordering, let's say $x_1x_2x_3x_4$ - and then I start with a high or a low $k$?

Comment: We start with $k=1$, in which case we need to decide which row is the first row (and we have $n$ branches based on that decision). From each of those, we have $n-1$ children with $k=2$ (based on the $n-1$ choices for the second row), then each of those has $n-2$ children with $k=3$ (based on the $n-2$ choices for the third row), and so on. This would give an $n!$ algorithm if we explored all the branches, and so we try to prune bad branches before that happens.

Comment: Check my update on the question - is that how you thought of it?

Comment: Maybe? I think? I'm not sure if you're using the same idea that I used to prune the branches, but who's to say your idea wouldn't work better for a $100\times 100$ matrix. (And the papers I looked at had some complicated pruning strategies.) I think you understand the basic idea and past that I'm not sure I can help you.

Comment: You already helped me really a lot...!!! I wish I could return the favor.. Anyway thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use simulated annealing. The sum of the entries of the upper matrix (including diagonal) provides the score. In each step, exchange two rows or two columns, picking row or column by throwing a fair die with 2 outcomes. Then pick two rows (or columns) uniformly at random and modify the matrix accordingly. The rest works as in the usual simulated annealing algorithm (lowering of temperature, calculation of Boltzmann factor). Terminate if the end temperature is reached or the overall score does not change for several rounds. Note that simulated annealing finds the global optimum under some conditions (result of Geman-Geman).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer... I am not sure if you understand me correctly but what I mean is if you change two elements, e.g. element 2 and 1 then you change BOTH row 2 with row 1 and column 2 with column 1 and just either row or column;

Comment: The problem originally comes from graph theory; I want to change the order of the vertices in such a way that the sum of edge weights $a_{ij}$ with $i \leq j$ is maximized... This it equivalent to changing both row and column...

Comment: Making the move from one step to the next one is up to you. In practice, simple moves are prefered.

Comment: Okay, thank you... And what about finding the optimal solution? And do you think the problem is NP-complete?

Comment: Requires reduction. But I guess so. The algorithm moves in each step from one solution (matrix) to a neighboring one. If NP, it will generally find only an approximate solution.

Comment: Okay I see... But if you have an idea left for a deterministic way let me know :-)